# Mongoose populate on Mixed property

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have the following (simplified) schemas:

```js
const user = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  email: String,
  profile: ObjectId
});

mongoose.model('User', user);

const profile = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  environment: Schema.Types.Mixed
});

mongoose.model('Profile', profile);

const fields = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String
});

mongoose.model('Field', fields);
```

The profile document looks like this:

```js
{
  "environment": {
    "field": [
      ObjectId("614cd51733966a3fa7d55ee6"),
      ObjectId("614cd51733966a3fa7d55ee7"),
      ObjectId("614cd51733966a3fa7d55ee8")
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try to populate `environment.field`, it doesn't work. The `field` property is always empty (`[]`).

This is what I'm trying:

```js
await User.findById(userId).populate({
  path: 'profile',
  populate: {
    path: 'environment.field',
    model: 'Field',
  },
});
```

From what I see on the console, the items on `environment.field` are simple strings instead of ObjectIds on the query even though they're ObjectIds on the database.

```js
users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5f288bf317a0e27ae3be5ccc") }, { collation: { caseLevel: true, locale: 'en_US', numericOrdering: true, strength: 1 }, projection: {}})

profiles.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5f288bf317a0e27ae3be5ccb") ] } }, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: { environment: 1 }})

fields.find({ _id: { '$in': [ '614cd52133966a3fa7d55ee9', '614cd56433966a3fa7d55f07', '614cd51733966a3fa7d55ee6', '614cd53c33966a3fa7d55ef2', '614cd54933966a3fa7d55ef9', '614cd56933966a3fa7d55f08', '614cd52a33966a3fa7d55eec', '614cd55933966a3fa7d55eff', '614cd54633966a3fa7d55ef5', '614cd56e33966a3fa7d55f0a' ] }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, sort: { name: 1 }, projection: { name: 1 }})
```

How I can populate `fields`?

Comment: Hello, why are you doing a populate into an other populate on your User.findById query ? Then, your schema are not good for population, you have no ref specifying which field that can be populated afterwards - check doc here : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hi @MathieuDfr. There's nothing wrong with using a populate inside another, it's a "deep populate" (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate). The difference from my code to the example on the doc is I don't have the `ref` attribute, but as far as I know passing the `model` option on the populate should work just as fine.

Comment: Hi, didn't know about the deep populate, my bad! As seen in the documentation, they always use ref to an other Model. I also checked on the api reference for populate, and there is no `model` properties/options possible. [https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)

Comment: @MathieuDfr it's there under "Available top-level options".